# Math matrix notation from Matlab notation

Tags: notation, matlab

I am trying to put the following (Matlab notation) into proper math notation and am having difficulty.

"When **X** and **Y** are matrices, **ix** and **iy** are such that **X**(:,**ix**) and **Y**(:,**iy**) are minimally separated"

I have defined **X**, **Y**, **ix**, and **iy**, the problem is that I don't know how to say **X**(:,**ix**) in math notation

Answer (score 2):

If $ix$ is a set of (column) indices, such as $[2,5,4]$, notation $X(:,ix)$ means the submatrix of $X$ obtained by taking all the lines (this is the meaning of the colon symbol), and the columns in the order found in $ix$; example with $ix=[2,5,4]$:

$$X=\pmatrix{1&4&11&3&5&7\\4&2&10&9&0&5} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ X(:,ix)=\pmatrix{4&5&3\\2&0&9}$$

But this description can be converted into this matrix operation:

$$\pmatrix{1&4&11&3&5&7\\4&2&10&9&0&5}\pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}=\pmatrix{4&5&3\\2&0&9}.$$

Edit: After a judicious remark of @littleO: Up to my knowledge, there is no commonly accepted mathematical convention for this kind of submatrix. Matlab notational conventions, at least in a certain "applied maths" community, are used as a substitute for non existing "classical maths" conventions.

Comment: Thank you. So the notation is the same?

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question.  OP already knew the meaning of the Matlab notation, and wanted to know the standard equivalent notation for mathematical writing.  I don't think Matlab notation is standard for mathematical writing, but you can use it as long as you first explain to the reader what it means.

Comment: @littleO right...I was assuming this was actually an answer to my question, i.e. that the answer IS in mathematical writing. I guess it isn't?

Comment: @littleO You are right: I hadn't take sufficient attention to the **real** question. And your answer is right too. I would even say that  Matlab notational conventions, at least in a certain "applied maths" community, are used as a substitute to non existing "classical maths" conventions. I had this to my answer.

Comment: @littleO See what I have added to my answer.